# Dropping out of PhD in my home country to start a new one in the UK

Tags: phd, application

I saw question similar to this but wanted to specify my problem. I did my Master in the UK and graduated in 2018 and decided to start PhD in my own country last year. As it took a little bit time to verify my degree in home country and application process had been closed, I had to apply in 2019 for 2020 academic year, hence the one year gap.

Now, however, I want to drop out of my PhD and apply for one in the UK. Significant difference in quality of education, lack of engagement with theoretical issues (and quite obsolete methods of doing things) and lack of usage of sources in English and my struggle to adapt again to academia of my own country are main reasons of my decision.

My question is:

How to explain it in my CV and justify it in order not to give a wrong impression? I mean, I could avoid writing that I had already started my PhD (which I did with my Master, applied already studying one in my own country and got offers from 5-6 UK universities) but filling the gap of 2-3 years constitutes another problem. Another thing might possibly be references because most people here do not have knowledge of English and it might sound odd asking them to write references for me.

What would be the best thing for me to do in this situation?

Comment: I think the explanation you give here is fine. Combine it with Covid disruptions... But it is what it is.

Comment: Should I say that I am currently doing my PhD on CV and then specify things I mentioned above on personal statement? Would it also be fine to get references from my previous university in the UK as I would not have completed this one by the time of application?

Comment: All of that sounds reasonable. I think reference from your MS experience are probably best, unless you have a good relationship with someone local.

Comment: Oh, thanks for support. Will try to write as articulately as possible to avoid any misunderstanding.